# Loop: Start program and kill after time out

Tags: zsh, kill, shell-script, infinite-loop, pid

for debugging reasons I want to spot one of those bugs showing up just occasionally. Therefore I want to code a while loop in the shell

- starting the program (if it will segfault => that's what I want)
- kill the program after a certain timeout (e.g. some seconds)

Problem here is that the PID will change. Can you give me a hint on how to perform this?
I use the zsh, but other shells are welcome too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#/usr/bin/env zsh
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
    echo "start sleep";
    sleep 30&
    LAST_CHILD=$!
    echo "PID\$!: "$LAST_CHILD;
    echo "wait for kill:"
    sleep 1 && kill -9 $LAST_CHILD;
done
```

should work with bash as well, but I still need some segfault detection so the loop aborts.

Comment: There's no need to use `seq`.

Comment: @Dennis: I know this is just an example, in practice I would use a while((true)) loop.

Comment: No, I meant `for i in {1..10}`.

Answer (score 4):

Timeout sounds like what you are looking for.

```
man timeout
timeout - run a command with a time limit
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done this for a while but the basic idea is to get the running shell to send it's PID to a named file before it starts looping and then read that file back in with a separate killer program that has the timer on it.  It's not "hard", but the devil's in the details...

Answer (score 1):

Try the bash script here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-scripting-run-command-under-alarmclock/

It does a spawn of a watchdog process that knows the PID of the subcommand to run.  Caveat: in this script, the command to kill needs to be the immediate child of the script.